# MySQL/PDO internal functioning

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I search Internal functionning with mysql. I have already read some function in MySQL API for C, for example mysql_store_result and mysql_use_result, and i have done some tests for PHP memory usage with both PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY values, but if PDO C code have allocated memory, i don't know how exactly it run (and Database storage temporary while mysql_free_result not called).

I am not searching answer here, but documentation about this. Have you link to recommend to me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start with a tutorial reference such as the following:
[Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Followed by browsing the official documentation here:
[PHP: PDO - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

These two references helped me get up to speed with PDO in no time, beware there are a few typos in the first link, nothing major.

Also SO has a heap on information on PDO such as creative static PDO objects to call (useful for OOP), inserting NULL values and other general 'troublshooting' issues.

Comment: thanks for answer but i know already this and i search internal functionment of mysql_store_result and mysql_use_result. Because PDO for MySQL, for default, store in themself a big memory for results, if you query "SELECT * FROM x", just in query, memory explose. I think it use mysql_store_result for default, but i want to go more far. Thanks